# JMeter looping through CSV

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, csv-file

I have two CSV files which I need to use in a loop. I am using jp@gc - Variables from CSV file. The contents are:

File #1

```
File successfuly parsed, 10 variables found:
${1} = e79d29ec-f356-4682-b601-fa6b41c1b40a
${2} = b0c4c235-60c4-462b-bab4-89e65da8e00c
..........
```

File #2

```
File successfuly parsed, 10 variables found:
${0} = 88F6470E3E45921AEC8240A4A1C837F323C96E5DB8D06F959A42CE068E5D6477
${1} = 2A2EE03FA798D359963C47F6DB97194BB2F6E053489DBE1539367697679E2D5E
```

I have a couple of of HTTP requests which will use these values, for each run every request has to take a new value from the CSV file. I have tried using the logic controllers with no luck. Anyone who had success with something similar willing to help me out?

Comment: Why you are not using the CSV Data Set Config?

Comment: Same question has been asked on SO by you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759127/jmeter-looping-through-csv

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `Loop Controller` and `CSV Data Set Config`. Firstly,  you need to define paramaters in `CSV Data Set Config` to extract information from your CSV file. You can reuse those paramaters in your HTTP requests. Secondly, you need a `Loop Controller` to loop through them a certain number of times.

To do so;

Add `CSV Data Set Config` to your Test Plan
Fill the File name something like : `./src/file/file1.csv`
Set File encoding : `UTF-8`
Enter variable name: `file1ID`

Do the same things for file2.csv

Add a `Thread Group` to your project
Add a `Loop Controller` under Thread group
Uncheck the checkbox in the `Loop Controller` and set Loop Count to 50 for example
Add a `HTTP Request` under the `Loop Controller`
Configure your `HTTP Request`
You may send as a parameter like this

```
api/getID?firstparameter=${file1ID}&secondparameter=${file2ID}
```

With this way everytime `${file1ID}` and `${file2ID}` should take a new value from the CSV files that you defined.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a Counter.

Set the upper limit to 10 and use the variable **i** inside the ${} in each request for entering those values from the CSV. For each request, the counter will increment and take new value from the CSV. 
[image]

Check if this helps.